# Decompile, edit and compile a .jar file

Tags: java, compilation, automation, decompiler

I am working on a program that automaticly decompiles and compiles java programs. The decompiling works now. But now i am stuck on the compiling of multiple java files in multiple packages. Can anyone help me to find acmd command for compiling a java project?

*And if possible make it support external libraries*

I hope i did not make that much grammar mistakes English is not my native 
language ;-)

Comment: `javac` is a command which compiles multiple java files in multiple packages and supports external libraries...

Comment: Note that this is unlikely to be successful in general, since decompilation and compilation are lossy processes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are at the application root folder trying to compile App.java file from com.example package that uses lib1.jar and lib2.jar libraries from lib folder to a destination bin folder, compilation command should have the following format:
***javac -d bin -sourcepath src -cp lib/lib1.jar;lib/lib2.jar src/com/example/App.java***

So 'bin/com/example/App.class' file should be created. If App.java uses other classes from the project, they all should be automatically compiled and put into corresponding folders.